# Probability of drawing a specific ball

Tags: probability

An urn contains $n$ red and $m$ blue balls. They are
withdrawn one at a time until a total of $r \leq n$,red balls have been withdrawn. Find the probability that a total of $k$ balls are withdrawn.

Hint: A total of $k$ balls will be withdrawn if there
are $r − 1$ red balls in the first $k − 1$ withdrawals
and the $k^{\text{th}}$ withdrawal is a red ball.

Answer : $\displaystyle\frac{\binom{n}{r-1} \binom{m}{k-r}(n-r + 1)}{\binom{n + m}{k-1}(n + m - k +1)}$.

Please explain me I am really struggling. Also I haven't understood the hint why it is $r-1$ red balls. Is it to show that red balls drawn are always less than the number of balls present initially?

It would be really helpful if someone can explain this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to rephrase this question, but not answer it.

An urn contains n red and m blue balls.

The game we play is that we will draw balls out of the urn until we draw r red balls. (r can't be more than n because you can't draw more red balls than there are in the urn)

We are trying to figure out the probability that we draw k balls.

Hint:
If you KNOW that you drew K balls, that means that your Kth draw was red, because that's the condition for ending the game. In other words, you end the game on your Kth draw if your Kth draw is your Rth red ball.

That implies that in the (K-1) draws before your Kth draw, you must have drawn (R-1) balls.

Further more, on that last draw, there were n - (r-1) red balls in the urn, and there were (n + m) - (k-1) total balls in the urn

Answer (score -1):

It might help to use specific numbers.  Suppose we want the chance that the third red ball $(r=3)$ is drawn on the fifth draw $(k=5).$  You need the fifth draw to be red.  You also need $2=r-1$ of the first $4=k-1$ balls to be red because if some other number were red the fifth ball is not the third red ball.  We would have to calculate the probability that the first four draws are two red and two black, followed by a red ball on the fifth draw.

In the answer, $\frac {{n \choose r-1}{m \choose k-r}}{n+m \choose k-1}$ is the chance we get $r-1$ red balls in the first $k-1$.  The first factor on the top is the number of ways to choose $r-1$ red balls out of the $n$ available.  The second is the number of ways to choose $k-r$ black balls out of the $m$ available.  The denominator is the total number of ways to choose $k-1$ balls without regard to color.  The rest of the answer is the chance of getting a red ball on the $k^{th}$ draw given that you got the proper mix in the first $k-1$ draws.